# Error JSF 2.1: java.io.FileNotFoundException:*/*.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext

Tags: spring, jsf-2, richfaces, spring-webflow-2

I have an a error in Jboss 7.0.2 "Arc", spring webflow 2.3.0.RELEASE with richfaces 4.0.0.Final(Myfaces 2.1.1):

> 12:34:19,729 SEVERE [org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) An exception occurred: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sections/login/header.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource.

when i run my login.xhtml page:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/flows/template/default.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<ui:define name="windowTitle">
#{msgs.loginTitle}
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="heading">
<ui:include src="/sections/login/header.xhtml"/>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="sidebarLeft">
<ui:include src="/sections/login/sidebarLeft.xhtml"/>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
<h:form>
   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      #{msgs.namePrompt}
      <h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}"/>
      #{msgs.passwordPrompt}
      <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}"/>
   </h:panelGrid>
   <p>
      <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.loginButtonText}"
                       action="planetarium"/>
   </p>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

The code of header.xhtml is:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
  <!--  <head><title>IGNORED</title></head> -->
  <body>
  <ui:composition>
     <div class="header">
        #{msgs.loginHeading}
     </div>
  </ui:composition>
  </body>
  </html>
```

the structure file is like this:

```
WEB-INF/flows/inscripcion
    inscripcion-flow.xhtml 
    inscripcion.xhtml    
    login.xhtml

WEB-INF/flows/sections/login
    header.xhtml
    sidebarLeft.xhtml

WEB-INF/flows/template
    template.xhtml
```

Why is this error?, I attached my Jboss Prompt

https://rapidshare.com/files/817066879/log12.zip
Thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have placed it in `WEB-INF/flows/sections/login/header.xhtml`. Fix the `src` accordingly to match this.

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/sections/login/header.xhtml"/>
```

Comment: Thnks, this work for me, there is another way to call this(header.xhtml)??, and is right the location of this in WEB-INF, because in JEE 6 Tutorial says:Web resources are any software artifacts that the web application requires
for proper rendering, including images, script files, and any
user-created component libraries. Resources must be collected in a standard location,which can be one of the following.
A resource packaged in the web application root must be in a subdirectory of a resources directory at the web application root:
resources/resource-identifier.

Comment: and A resource packaged in the web application’s classpath must be in a subdirectory of the META-INF/resources directory within a web
application: META-INF/resources/resource-identifier.

Comment: Another way is to use a path which is relative to current template (i.e. don't start with `/`). But that's not recommended. Resources are static files like CSS, JS, images, etc. Templates can perfectly be placed in `/WEB-INF`. It hides them from direct access (you cannot open `http://localhost:8080/contextname/WEB-INF/*` files by webbrowser).